# Normal Viscous Stress (Newtonian Incompressible Flow)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I have been struggling to understand why normal viscous stresses are often neglected in elementary fluid mechanics analysis (see examples below). Usually, the justification is something in the lines of "viscous normal stresses are extremely small in all but rare cases, such as the interior of a shock wave" (Fluid Mechanics. White, Frank M.). I'm sure that I'm misinterpreting this sentence though: The deviatoric stress tensor (the tensor you get after subtracting the mean stress) is symmetric and therefore diagonalizable, which implies that if every normal viscous stress is negligible so are the shear viscous stresses - an absurd.

Examples:

(1) Energy Balance for Control Volumes: Flow work is calculated neglecting normal viscous stresses. In fact, in thermodynamics texts this assumption that pressure (and pressure only) is the resistance to flow leads to the definition of enthalpy;

(2) Linear Momentum Balance for Control Volumes: Many textbook examples warn about the necessity of recognizing shear (viscous) stresses on the control surface, for instance when the surface protrudes the boundary layer of an external flow. Nothing is ever said about normal viscous stresses, though;

(3) Analytical solution of laminar flow over a flat plate: In solving the Navier-Stokes equations, the second derivative of u (horizontal component of the velocity) with respect to x is assumed negligible. In this example, it is the derivative of the normal shear stress that is neglected, again without due justification. But what's most remarkable is that this time the derivative of u with respect to x (and therefore the normal viscous stress) is not neglected, casting doubt on the "normal viscous stresses are negligible" argument.

Please, neglect effects due to compressibility.

Comment: In my judgment, it is because the normal viscous stresses always combine with the isotropic part of the stress tensor, namely the pressure, and the normal viscous stresses are usually much smaller than the pressure.  On the other hand, the pressure is not present in combination with the shear stresses.